# How to get number of rows in example section of scenario outline Cucumber Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

I would like to know how to get number of rows present in example section of a scenario outline in cucumber java and Junit based framework

For examples if i have a test case like

```
Scenario Outline: my test case 1
Given Step1
And Step2
When Step 3
Then Step 4
Examples:
|a|
|b|
|c|
|d|
```

Since i have 4 rows here, I would like to retrieve number 4 during my execution

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: To create a loop and update results accordingly. Is there any way to find number of rows?